# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'minelauncher'

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных

Есть переменные

````
    protected String dbHost = "localhost";
    protected String dbPort = "3306";
    protected String dbUser = "root";
protected String dbPass= "56";
protected String dbName = "minelauncher";
public class Databases extends mineClass{

    Connection dbConnection;
    public Connection getDbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    String connectionString =  "jdbc:mysql://" +dbHost+ ":"+ dbPort +"/" + dbName;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbUser, dbPass);
        return dbConnection;

    }
    public void SingUpUser(String id,String login, String password) {
        String insert = "INSERT INTO"+Constant.USER_TABLE+"("+Constant.USERS_ID+","+Constant.USERS_LOGIN+","+Constant.USER_PASSWORD+")"+
    "VALUES(?,?,?)";


        try {
            PreparedStatement prSt = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
            prSt.setString(1, id);
            prSt.setString(2, login);
            prSt.setString(3, password);
            prSt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    }```
````

Comment: Я создал новую базу данных, с именем minelauncher1, в ней почему-то были те же таблицы, что и в minelauncher, во всех создаваемых базах данных, у меня те же таблицы. И в новой базе данных "minelauncher1" такая же проблема, что он не видит данную базу данных

Comment: Попробуйте: String con = "SERVER=" + host + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
      database + ";" + "UID=" + username + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

      MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(con);